# Problems when overriding method of parent class

Tags: python, class, parent

I'm doing the Python course on Codedemy. I'm at the part where they teach about classes and object oriented programming. I'm struggling with inheritance. I get this error message when trying to override the parents method:

```
<bound method PartTimeEmployee.full_time_wage of <__main__.PartTimeEmployee object>>
```

In this code:

```
class Employee(object):
    """Models real-life employees!"""
    def __init__(self, employee_name):
        self.employee_name = employee_name

    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 20.00


class PartTimeEmployee(Employee):
    def calculate_wage(self, hours):
        self.hours = hours
        return hours * 12.00

    def full_time_wage(self):
        super(PartTimeEmployee, self).calculate_wage(self, hours)

milton = PartTimeEmployee("Milton")

print milton.full_time_wage
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: That's not an error message. Error messages always say "error" and/or "exception" (and if you get them unexpectedly rather than handling them an printing them, they also give you a traceback).

Answer (score 4):

`print milton.full_time_wage()`

so you call the function ....

that isnt an error ... you just were printing a function .... not the return value

Comment: Technically, he's not printing a function, but a bound method. But yeah, close enough for the level of precision the OP is likely to understand.